# JavaFX Key Pressed event for scene not executed if there is a focused component

Tags: java, javafx

I have a code to execute some function when some key is pressed:

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.F1) {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

And it works, but only if there is no focused components, like a Button or a TextField.
I noticed it works if i press CTRL+F1, or ALT+F1, or SHIFT+F1, but only F1 just works if there is no focused component.
Is there a way to avoid this?

**-----UPDATE-----**
As @James_D said, i can do it using eventFilter instead of eventHandler:

```
scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
    if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ESCAPE)) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(TelaPrincipalController.class.getResource("/br/com/atualy/checkout/layout/telaoperacoescaixa.fxml"));
            Parent parent = fxmlLoader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(parent, 600,400);
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.initOwner(this.stage);
            stage.showAndWait();
            System.out.println("----> THIS IS BEING PRINTED TWICE ! <----");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

The line 12 in this code gets printed twice for every ESC key press. Which means that when i press esc, it opens the new window, and when i close it, the window opens one more time.
Can i solve it?

Comment: Not really sure why that is happening, but you can fix it by consuming the event after your `System.out.println(...)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use an event filter instead. Some controls consume key press events, so using an event filter allows you to handle them before the control consumes them.

```
scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,
                event -> System.out.println("Pressed: " + event.getCode()));
```

Comment: Looks like event filter is executed twice, if inside the code i open a new Modal window. See my update in the question please

Comment: Try using `KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED` instead of `KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED`.

Comment: Why using this line gives me a,  **method addEventFilter in class Scene cannot be applied to given types;
  required: EventType<T>,EventHandler<? super T>
  found: int,(event)->S[...]de())** compile time error